# Exchanging the pixel_array for a DICOM RT Dose file - values change - pydicom

Tags: python, dicom, pydicom

I have a DICOM RT Dose file that I want to change the original pixel_array with a new one. The problem is that when I give a certain pixel its new value, somewhere in the process it changes randomly. The block of code for the exchange is given below. I do the exchange one pixel at a time only to check where the problem is, so I know it can be done much faster:

```
print pixel_arrayFLK[86][85][78]
print dosem.pixel_array[86][85][78]
for a in range(zBinsTPS):
    for b in range(yBinsTPS):
        for c in range(xBinsTPS):
            dosem.pixel_array[a][b][c] = pixel_arrayFLK[a][b][c]
            if a == 86 and b == 85 and c == 78:
                print dosem.pixel_array[a][b][c]
                print pixel_arrayFLK[a][b][c]
```

The original pixel_array is the dosem.pixel_array and new one is the pixel_arrayFLK. As an example of what happens:

pixel_arrayFLK[86][85][78] has the value 65813. The original dosem.pixel_array[86][85][78] has the value 62947. After the exchange pixel_arrayFLK[86][85][78] still has the value 65813 whereas dosem.pixel_array[86][85][78] suddenly now has the value 277.

Print functions yield:

```
65813
62947
277
65813
```

However, if I divide all the values of pixel_arrayFLK by 2, the exchange works fine. I really do not understand what's happening. Does it maybe has something to do with the data type in the DICOM file? Some more information contained in the DICOM:

```
(0028, 0002) Samples per Pixel                   US: 1
(0028, 0004) Photometric Interpretation          CS: 'MONOCHROME2'
(0028, 0100) Bits Allocated                      US: 16
(0028, 0101) Bits Stored                         US: 16
(0028, 0102) High Bit                            US: 15
(0028, 0103) Pixel Representation                US: 0
(7fe0, 0010) Pixel Data                          OW or OB: Array of 6750000 bytes
```

I have another DICOM file where the Bits Allocated = 32, Bits Stored = 32 and High Bit = 31. The pixel_array exchange in this file works seemingly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. As the bits are 16, the maximum value is 65536, where 65813 overrides this value by 277, and therefore start at 0.